# Access Pipeline object in an ndb transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I tried running a function that contains this line in an ndb transaction. I was getting `AttributeError: 'Key' object has no attribute 'reference'` and I can see that it is due to this line.

`pipeline = MyPipeline.from_id(pipline_id)`

`MyPipeline` is a subclass of `mapreduce.base_handler.PipelineBase` (from the mapreduce library).

But this runs fine without a transaction. Is it impossible to access Pipeline objects within an ndb transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the pipeline before the transaction, and reference it from within the transaction.

```
pipeline = MyPipeline.from_id(pipeline_id)

@ndb.transactional(retries=5)
def _tx():
  # do stuff to pipeline
  # ...

_tx()
```

**The reason you are seeing the failure is due to the fact that the mapreduce pipeline is implemented with db, not ndb.**

If fetching the Pipeline with `.from_id()` fails for any reason, the code will raise an exception, and your transaction won't run in the first place - which is what you want.

The benefit of using a transaction is usually for knowing whether or not changes are applied to the datastore across a set of entities. Fetching an entity, in this case - the pipeline, is not an action that modifies any data.